# undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3pcl7console5printENS0_15VERBOSITY_LEVELEPKcz'

Tags: c++, cmake, point-cloud-library

`I am simply trying to compile a program in ROS . I already linked all the necessary libraries but this one I can't find. All I am getting is the following error in codeblocks (also in eclipse).

Anybody know how to get rid of this error? Or even which library it require?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(gpuvoxelgetpointcloud)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
cmake_modules  
roscpp
rospy
std_msgs
sensor_msgs
cv_bridge
image_transport
pcl_conversions
pcl_ros
)
find_package(icl_core REQUIRED )
find_package(gpu_voxels REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED)
find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)




#include <pcl_ros/transforms.h>
#include <pcl/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/PCLPointCloud2.h>
```

Error is:

undefined reference to symbol

```
'_ZN3pcl7console5printENS0_15VERBOSITY_LEVELEPKcz'
```

`//use/lib/aarch64_linux-gnu/  libpcl-common.so.1.7: error adding symbols:DSO missing from command line          collect2:ld returned 1 exit status.`
I am using plc on TX2 and maybe there is something wrong with plc on arm.

Comment: Use `nm` or `objdump` to search every library you have installed, and grep for that symbol.

Comment: A quick in-head demangling + a google search suggests that you may be missing an include for pcl/pcl_macros.h. Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the followings to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories(
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Also, link `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` to your targets. Include the necessary header files in your cpp codes.